# Populate numberOfSectionsInTableView using an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective C and I'm trying to specify the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` in my tableView here is my code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_dateSectionTitles count];
}
```

The `[_dateSectionTitles count]` always returns a zero.

This is how i get `_dateSectionTitles`

```
- (void) dictionaryItems {
    NSMutableDictionary* dates = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    _dateSectionTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (myObject *cItem in _cashArray) {
        NSString* dateString = [cItem.date stringFormattedWithDayAndFullMonth];
        array = [dates valueForKey: dateString];
        if(!array)
        {
            array = [@[cItem] mutableCopy];
            [dates setObject:array forKey: dateString];
            [_dateSectionTitles addObject:dateString];
        }
        else
        {
            [array addObject: cItem];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From taking a quick look, it looks like `array` is never declared. Meaning that the else statement of your condition is always executed and nothing is added to `dateSectionTitles`.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [dates valueForKey: dateString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you never instantiate your `array` variable. you need to have to have this somewhere:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: it's declared in my `@interface ViewController () {
    NSMutableArray* array;
}`

Comment: Thats not enough. Based on your **else** you have to initialize it or no object will ever be added. That is probably what is happening. Declaring it is not enough, you need to initialize it to use **[array addobject: cItem]**

Comment: Also in your if - else.... if array = [dates valueForString: dateString] always returns an array nothing will ever be added to _dateSectionTitles because only your else statement will be executed.